# What's the equivalent to Dataframe.append() in Pandas v 2.1

Tags: python, pandas, version

I think that the attribute "append" is no longer available for the newer versions of pandas, and i'd like to know what's the equivalent of it now

I was trying to do a dataframe with a for loop, then i used DataFrame.append to add the dataframe created to a new variable, but i got the error:'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'append'

Comment: note, you *shouldn't* be using `.append` in a loop to begin with, create a list then use `mylist.append(some_df)` in the loop, then use `final = pd.concat(my_list)` at the end (which should work on the latest versions)

Comment: See `https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/1.5/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.append.html`, in which it mentions when `append` was deprecated and what to use instead.